# Limit of a sequence of characteristic functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

This limit seems very obvious: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \chi_{[0,n]} = \chi_{[0,\infty]} $

but I'm having a struggle in proving it.

Given $\epsilon >0$, I'm needing to find a $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$ $\|\chi_{[0,n]} - \chi_{[0,\infty]} \|< \epsilon$.

$\|\chi_{[0,n]} - \chi_{[0,\infty]} \| = 0$ when $x \in \chi_{[0,n]} \cap \chi_{[0,\infty]}$, but how to properly justify there will be $x$ in this set $\forall n>n_0$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can show pointwise convergence (ie the function values converge at any given $x$), but not uniform convergence.

Comment: How can I write $n_0$ for pointwise convergence?

Comment: You should write $\chi_{[0,n]} \to \chi_{[0,\infty)}$ pointwise on $[0,\infty).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x):=\chi_{[0,n]}(x)$ and $f(x):=\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$

Case 1: $x<0$. Then $f_n(x)=0 \to 0 =f(x)$ for $ n \to \infty$

Case 2: $x \ge 0$.. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x \in [0,N]$. Hence  $x \in [0,n]$  for all $n \ge N$. Thus

$f_n(x)=1 $ for all $n \ge N$. It follows that

$f_n(x) \to 1 =f(x)$ for $ n \to \infty$

Comment: Thanks. Another doubt: This sequence is increasing? Isn't it constant for every $x \in [0,n]$?

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comment pointwise convergence can be shown, so you have to show $\|\chi_{[0,n]}(x) - \chi_{[0,\infty]}(x) \|< \epsilon$ for a given $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Obviously for $n \ge x$ it holds $\|\chi_{[0,n]}(x) - \chi_{[0,\infty]}(x) \| = 0 < \epsilon$